# Accessing nested dictionary in Python 3.5

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm importing a nested dictionary from an external file and trying to access values in the deepest level; however, when I try to use `for` loops I get the following error:

```
print(country['unicode'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The dictionary I'm importing (from a file `emojiFlags.py`) looks like this:

```
flagSet = {'emojiFlagSet': {'Andorra': {'emoji': '', 'unicode': 
'U+1F1E6 U+1F1E9'}, 'Afghanistan': {'emoji': '', 'unicode': 'U+1F1E6 
U+1F1EB'}, ... }}
```

etc. etc.

Here are the snippets of code I'm working with:

```
from emojiFlags import flagSet

# Get country emoji data
for country in flagSet['emojiFlagSet']:
    print(country['unicode'])
```

I'm fairly certain I've done something like this on a number of other dictionaries before (and had no problems), and I'm wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing at this point.

Oddly, if I `print(flagSet)`, my return is `emojiFlagSet` (the key), not its value (a dictionary); however, if I `print(flagSet['emojiFlagSet'])` the return is the entire nested dictionary value as it should be. If I instead try

```
for country in flagSet['emojiFlagSet']:
    print(country)
```

I get all of the country names, but, just like with the `print(flagSet)` statement, I only get the keys and not their nested dictionary values.

My end goal is to simply return the value of the `'unicode'` keys within each country's dictionary. So, I'd expect to see

```
U+1F1E6 U+1F1E9
```

for the first country, for example.

Strangest of all, if I do

```
print(flagSet['emojiFlagSet']['Andorra']['unicode'])
```

as a simple test, I get exactly what I'm looking for. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong in my `for` loop?

Comment: Iterate over `.values()`? `print(flagSet[‘emojiFlagSet’][country][‘unicode’])`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe just saw your comment... thanks for the feedback! It seems this (your second suggestion) is what I've used before and just forgot about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the dictionary itself, which yields the *keys* for that dictionary. In your `flagSet['emojiFlagSet']` dictionary, those keys are strings (such as `'Andorra'` and `'Afghanistan'`).

You wanted the values instead, it is the values that are dictionaries too. Loop over [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

```
for country in flagSet['emojiFlagSet'].values():
    print(country['unicode'])
```

Note that the fact that you imported the datastructure from another module has no bearing on all of this.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't worked with dict.values() before (it's been a while since I worked with Python). I just solved my problem by changing my `print` statement to `print(flagSet['emojiFlagSet'][country]['unicode'])`. Other than readability issues, is there a performance reason I might use `.values()` instead?

Comment: @BenjaminAlanWallsten: well, yes, having to do 2 additional item lookups each time in the loop will be a teensy bit slower. Dictionaries are key-value pairs; if all you want are the values, just loop over the values. That's not really Python-specific, by the way; C# and C++ and Java offer dictionaries too (but Java and C++ call them maps).

Comment: That makes sense (and seems so obvious in hindsight - one of the dangers of early stage self-teaching, I suppose). `.values()` it is then! Much appreciated!